AsyncStorage not waiting with "then" in React Native
I am having some trouble trying to get an Item from AsyncStorage in React Native without transform it into an async function and use await.
Based on this answer, I was trying to do something like this:
const getItem = (key) => {  
  AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token").then(value=>{
    console.log(value, " first")
    return value
  });
};

const test = () => {
  const teste = getItem()
  console.log(teste, " final"); 
}

The crazy part is when a call test function (on a onPress event, for instance), I get the following printed:
LOG  undefined  final
LOG  00b3ceb97ae8d9357abd1065f50be408a9389f23  first

The final log, which should be displayed at the end, is printed first and is undefined.
Edit:
Another try:
const getItem = (key) => {  
  const value = AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token").then(value=>{
    console.log(value, " first")
    return value
  });

  console.log(value, " second")

};

This is the log:
LOG  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}  second
LOG  00b3ceb97ae8d9357abd1065f50be408a9389f23  first

Am I missing something here? Is it possible to use "then" to get data with AsyncStorage lib without the async await mechanism?
"react-native": "0.73.6" and "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",

Does this answer your question? How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?

The return statement returns from the value => {} function, not from the getItem() function. To return from the getItem() function the return statement CANNOT be inside another function (this means it must be outside the .then()). As you can see, you've put yourself in an impossible situation. The correct solution is to either pass a callback to getItem() or remove the .then() and do return AsyncStorage.getItem()

your getItem does not return anything. And even if it was (for instance by return AsyncStorage.getItem(...).then(...), it would return a promise, which then you will have again to eiter await getItem() or use getItem().then(...)

I don't think so. I guess I am using the Promise.then method right, isn't it? If I do the code with async await it works well. Is is a limitation of AsyncStorage? Does it work only with async await? Or Am I missing something?

@slebetman  Even if getItem had a return AsyncStorage.getItem(...) OP is also not using getItem correctly, because he is not awaiting its result ...

Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Take a look at the edit version. The "second is been printed first....

Well, of course it is, because you are not waiting for the promise returned by .then(...) The two questions I linked for reference, explain in every detail how async code works. Read them carefully, and you will probably notice what you are doing wrong. There is no point in explaining this all here once again.

"I guess I am using the Promise.then method right, isn't it?"  No you are not, neither in your original code nor in your updated code. Read the linked questions to understand why ...

Sorry, guys. Now I got it.
I thought that with "then" was not necessary to wait the response. I can only works inside the "then" function. My mistake.

I was having a total misunderstanding of the use of "then". I thought that with it I did not have to wait and use the response outside.
const getItem = (key) => {  
  const value = AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token").then(value=>{
    // here i can use it without wait. To set a useState, for instance.
    return value
  });
  console.log(value) // this is not gonna work.
};

Thanks, @derpirscher and @slebetman

In your case I suggest to return Promise from getItem and use then after:
const getItem = (key) => {  
  return AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token").then(value => {
    console.log(value, " first");
    return value
  });
};

const test = () => {
  getItem().then((value) => console.log(value, " final"));
}

